# Bootstrap: responsive div in between two fixed div elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a responsive `<div>` element placed in between two fixed `<div>` elements. I've tried the following code:

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Sample1</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 </head>
 <body>
     <div style="width: auto">
         <div style="float: left; width:270px; background-color: green">Fixed div</div>
         <div style="float: right; width: 120px; background-color: yellow"> Fixed div</div>
         <div style="background-color: red" class="row">Responsive div</div>        
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Currently the responsive `<div>` element is taking the whole screen. When I try to checkout the width and height, it has acquired my entire main `<div>`. Is there any approach where I can put this responsive `<div>` inside 2 fixed `<div>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below code: Here I have altered Div sequence and change display style of the three.

```html
<html>
 <head>
   <title>Sample1</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div style="display:table; width:100%">
    <div style="display:table-cell; width:270px; background-color: green">Fixed div </div>
    <div style="background-color: red; display:table-cell;"> Responsive div </div>
    <div style="display:table-cell; width: 120px; background-color: yellow"> Fixed div</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you got their div widths already, we can took advantage of the `calc`

```
width: calc(100% - 390px);
```

The `390px` value is the sum of the width of left and ride side elements.

```html
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Sample1</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div style="width: auto">
    <div style="float: left; width:270px; background-color: green">Fixed div </div>
    <div style="float: right; width: 120px; background-color: yellow"> Fixed div</div>
    <div style="background-color: red;  width: calc(100% - 390px);margin-left: 270px;" class="row"> Responsive div </div>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
<body style="display:table;width:100%;">
  <div style="float: left; width:270px; background-color: green;display:table-cell;">Fixed div </div>
  <div style="background-color: red;display:table-cell;" class="row"> Responsive div </div>  
  <div style="float: right; width: 120px; background-color: yellow;display:table-cell;"> Fixed div</div>  
</body>
```